# Solve $|x^2-a^2|=a^2-x$, $a>1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Solve $|x^2-a^2|=a^2-x$, where $a>1$.

The first line of the model answer http://image.prntscr.com/image/6da5a4db6ec740718f0a149401eaf478.png has:

$$x^2-a^2=a^2-x.$$

Why have they done this?

- This was part of a Model Answer to a question on inequalities in June'09 Edexcel FP2 paper.
- Question 7 on examiners report for FP2: http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/A%20Level/Mathematics/2013/Exam%20materials/8371_9374_GCE_Maths_rep_20090813_UA021531.pdf does not give much further info.

Answer: There are two cases:

1. $x^2-a^2=a^2-x$
2. $x^2-a^2=-a^2+x$

I just concentrated on the first line without realising the second case

Comment: Question updated. Please review

Comment: Check a=2, x=0. It is not equivalent

Comment: All that was given in the question was: $|x^2-a^2|=a^2-x$, and $a>1$.

Comment: Like I said, I found an a and x for which the first equation is true, the second one is not

Comment: Ok I agree with you, so I am wondering if the model answer is wrong then

Comment: Here's the [answer](http://image.prntscr.com/image/6da5a4db6ec740718f0a149401eaf478.png) to that question on my model answer sheet

Comment: It's split into two separate [cases](http://image.prntscr.com/image/01ee0bcd0db748cc8eb1b395931d6f2b.png)

Comment: @flametrap Do you have the link to the whole model answers for that paper?

Comment: [Here](http://pmt.physicsandmathstutor.com/download/Maths/A-level/FP2/Papers-Edexcel/June%202009%20MA%20-%20FP2%20Edexcel.pdf)

Comment: The model sheet does _two_ cases. It would have been clearer if they indicated that there were two cases. So in _your_ work, recognizing the potential for confusion, you should do better than the model sheet.

Comment: @Flame Trap: Had you posted, as part of your initial question, an image of the model sheet's full solution to the problem, that would have avoided a lot of confusion.

Comment: What is your question? "Why have they done this?" doesn't tell us who "they" are or what "this" is. You can't expect MSE readers to work through a long PDF document trying to work out which of the 18 matches to "Question 7"s are relevant.

Comment: Oh, my comments to Flame Trap were intended for the OP (@unseen_rider). Sorry for the misdirect.

Answer (score 1):

An equation of the form $|A|=B$ is equivalent to the set of equations
$$
A=B\qquad A=-B
$$
provided $B\ge0$.

In your case
$$
x^2-a^2=a^2-x
\qquad
x^2-a^2=x-a^2
$$
Just solve the two quadratics and consider the roots of both.

You see in the image a large white space to separate the solutions of the two quadratics.

After that, check what roots satisfy $a^2-x\ge0$.

The solutions are
$$
\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+8a^2}}{2}
\qquad
\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8a^2}}{2}
\qquad
0
\qquad
1
$$
Which ones are good?

Comment: The equation $|A|=B$ is condtional on $B\ge 0$. So after solving for $x$, you need to check those conditions, and reject any solutions which fail to satisfy. Alternatively, split it as 

$$A = B \text{ and }A \ge 0$$

$$-A = B \text{ and } A < 0$$

Comment: @quasi Thanks, I should have been more careful.